Torus knot of type (1,p) is trivial?
Let $T_{1,p}: S^1 \to S^3\subseteq \mathbb{C}^2, \ z \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(z,z^p)$ be the torus knot of type $(1,p)$ with $p \in \mathbb{Z}$. Further let $U: S^1 \to S^3, \ z \mapsto (z,0)$ be the unknot. Let also $T_{1,p} = \text{Im}(T_{1,p})$ and $U := \text{Im}(U)$.
What is an explicit (and probably natural) homeomorphism $\varphi: S^3 \to S^3$ with $\varphi(U) = T_{1,p}$ or maybe $\varphi \circ U = T_{1,p}$?
In the case $p=0$ with the identification $\mathbb{R}^3\cup\{\infty\} = S^3$ a choice for $\varphi$ should be the extension of the homeomorphism
$$\phi: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, \ x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+e_3)$$
to $S^3$ (i.e. $(\varphi(\infty) = \infty)$), because $T_{1,p}$ would be $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x,1) \ | \ x\in S^1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3\cup \{\infty\} = S^3$ and $U$ would be $\{(x,0) \ | \ x\in S^1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3\cup \{\infty\} = S^3$.
But I don't see such an easy way for $p \neq 0$? Also using the identification $S^1\ast S^1 = S^3$ via $\langle(w,z), (a,b)\rangle \mapsto (\sqrt{a}w,\sqrt{b}z)$ and $T_{1,p} = \{\langle (z,z^p),  (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) \rangle \ | \ z \in S^1 \} \subseteq S^1\ast S^1 = S^3$ I do not see a natural homeomorphism.

I don't think there can be any expectation at all of a "natural" homeomorphism, there are simply too many little choices that one must make in the construction of the desired homeomorphism.
If you change coordinates on $S^3$ this becomes easier. Namely, use stereographic coordinates, which converts $S^3$ into the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R^3$. It now comes down to keeping track of the image of the knot in $\mathbb R^3$, and applying an appropriate homeomorphism of $\mathbb R^3$ which takes the knot to the standard unit circle in the $xy$-coordinate plane.
Under the stereographic coordinate change (possibly with additional factors applied in $\mathbb R^3$), the image of the torus $S^1 \times S^1 \subset \mathbb C \times \mathbb C$ becomes a standard torus of rotation, expressed in $(\theta,r,z)$ cylindrical coordinates as $(r-2)^2 + z^2 = 1$. The image of the torus knot becomes $(\theta,2 +\cos(p \theta), \sin(p \theta))$. Projecting this to the $x,y$ plane gives a trivial knot diagram, i.e. a knot diagram with no crossings, expressed as an embedded circle in the $x,y$-plane. In fact this trivial knot diagram is parameterized in polar coordinates as $r=2+\cos(p\theta)$. You can then define a radial projection of the entire plane: $(r,\theta) \mapsto \bigl(r / (2+\cos(p\theta)),\theta\bigr)$, taking the knot diagram to the standard circle. Putting these pieces together you can construct the desired homeomorphism $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$.
